# Interpretation of etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

We know that
$$\operatorname{FiniteEtale}(X) \cong \operatorname{LocalSystem}_{X}(\text {FiniteSet})$$

So how does one interpret the etale cohomology of a finite local system with the corresponding finite etale cover? (Also is this equivalence giving the espace etale?)

Comment: I mean the cohomology of the topos on the other side recovers, essentially, the group cohomology of $\pi_1^\mathrm{et}$. For pro-finite local systems the two cohomologies agree for $i=1$, but usually for higher $i$. One calls $X$ where the two agree for all $i$ so-called $K(\pi,1)$'s. I would suggest looking at the PhD thesis of Piotr Achinger.